# Erro na execução deste comando

Tags: openssl

Comando:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -in pass -K str -iv str -nosalt -base64 -A -out $pass
```

Erro:

> non-hex digit invalid hex iv value

str é uma string hexadecimal com 32 carateres

Não estou a conseguir ultrapassar isto. Se puderem ajudar, seria ótimo!

Answer (score 1):

No seu comando os `str` e um dos `pass` esta sem cifrão ($), portanto está sendo passada como valor e não como variável.

Provavelmente o comando que você deseja é:

`openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -in $pass -K $str -iv $str -nosalt -base64 -A -out $pass`

Porém, vejo outros problemas com o comando:

- O IV (`-iv`) e a chave (`-K`) não deveriam ter o mesmo valor.
- Não usar salt (`-nosalt`) é uma má ideia.

Essas configurações podem diminuir drasticamente a segurança da criptografia, dependendo de como você a usa. Sugiro que você busque o que cada um desses parâmetros fazem e como lidar com eles de uma forma segura.